# IPA characters with tipa in Beamer poster switch to small font size, cannot be set to normal font size

Tags: beamer, fonts, posters, tipa, size

I am using package `tipa` in order to have IPA characters at my disposal. However, when used in conjunction with `beamer` poster, the `tipa` characters switch to small font size. Setting them to another font size still leaves the IPA characters in small size (although the ordinary characters are now printed larger).

What can I do about this? Please see my minimal example below.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} 
\mode<presentation> {  
\usetheme{Berlin}   
}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug] {beamerposter}                       % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster

\usepackage{tipa}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
\maketitle

\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.30\linewidth}


\begin{block}{\large Title}
\textless Causeway is\textgreater ~pronounced as \textipa{[k\textopeno zwe\textsci \textglotstop \textsci z]}
\end{block}
\vfill
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The TIPA fonts are not scalable. The largest available size is 36pt.  I would recommend that you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and a Unicode font that has phonetic characters.

Comment: or use a smaller pagesize like a4 and check if the font still looks good when printed on a0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font definition file for the sans serif version of the tipa fonts assumes they are not scalable, but in modern TeX distributions they are. So just tell LaTeX so.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} 
\mode<presentation> {  
\usetheme{Berlin}   
}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug] {beamerposter}                       % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster

\usepackage{tipa}

\DeclareFontFamily{T3}{cmss}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{cmss}{m}{n}{%
  <-8.5> tipass8
  <8.5-9.5> tipass9
  <9.5-11> tipass10
  <11-15> tipass12
  <15-> tipass17
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{cmss}{bx}{n}{%
  <-> tipasb10
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{cmss}{m}{sl}{%
  <-> tipasi10
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{cmss}{m}{it}{%
  <-> sub * cmss/m/sl
}{}


\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
\maketitle

\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.30\linewidth}


\begin{block}{\large Title}
\textless Causeway is\textgreater ~pronounced as 
\textipa{[k\textopeno zwe\textsci \textglotstop \textsci z]}
\end{block}
\vfill
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this scale arbitrarily because of the `<15->`?

Comment: @AlanMunn Not only: as you see all the other fonts cover intervals, rather than discrete steps like in the original; in this case, the font size is above 15pt, so `tipass17` is used, scaled as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Alan Munn suggested using a Unicode font, and since there are a few tricks to it, here’s how.  You get a lot of other bonuses this way, such as being able to enter Unicode source and copy IPA from the file correctly.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {    
}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug] {beamerposter}                       % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Changes here:
\usepackage{fontspec}       % Apparently defines most aliases from TIPA.

%% I chose DejaVu Sans here because it matches the sans-serif font of the
%% theme you’re using (it’s slightly heavier), has full support for IPA, and
%% is widely available.  Another good choice is Charis SIL.

\newfontfamily\ipafamily{DejaVu Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

%% Switch to a font with IPA symbols that match the other glyphs, and sets it
%% to the same x-height as the main font.
\DeclareRobustCommand\ipa[1]{{\ipafamily\textipa{#1}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
\maketitle

\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.30\linewidth}


\begin{block}{\large Title}
\textless{}Causeway is\textgreater ~pronounced as \ipa{[k\textopeno zwe\textsci \textglotstop \textsci z] or [kɑzweɪʔz]}
\end{block}
\vfill
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: How do I pronounce causeway?]

Comment: I do think it is not necessary to add “Formalities”. This site already has license attributed to any contents.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!  Just put it there in case somebody’s company policy needed a license.  Removed now.

Comment: +1 Great answer, thank you so much. I particularly like that it's possible to interpret IPA directly.